# Существует ли iOS эмулятор для Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, ios, эмулятор

Если нет, то имеются ли аналоги под эту ОС?

Comment: Аналоги чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет таких. Единственный более-менее нормальный способ это установить на виртуалке VMWare нечто вроде [хакинтоша](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2011/09/how-to-install-fully-functional-mac-os-x-lion-virtual-machine-inside-windows-7/) и юзать там. Метод кривой - очень кривой, но рабочий.

Гораздо проще купить Mac Mini и получить легальную рабочую версию.

Comment: Хакинтош и установка на виртуалку - это разные вещи :) На вирт. машине, кстати, если железо позволяет, можно сравнительно комфортно кодить. Сам пробовал как-то.

Comment: Согласен, хакинтош и установка на виртуалку это разные вещи, но речь то шла о том, чтобы все работало на винде, оттуда и предложение установки хакинтоша под виртуалку. Конечно, хакинтош на железе гораздо веселее чем на виртуалке

Comment: Скажем так, эмуляторов iOS в принципе не существует. Есть симулятор. Разница достаточно-таки большая и ощутимая между двумя этими сущностями. В остальном автор прав.

Comment: Ну вообще-то при более-менее современной хост-машине (основной затык - поддержка аппаратной виртуализации на проце) на виртуалку уже можно поставить и нормальный мак, не хакинтош, виртуалбокс точно позволяет, вмваре кажется тоже

Comment: Сразу видно человек не ставил... Поставить то можно, а работать по человечески (девелопить) все равно толком нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

А вы пробовали писать под винду на маке или линуксе? Думаю, что нет :) и не сможете, так и тут - если пишешь под что-то конкретное, нужно это конкретное иметь под рукой. А так, это все равно что писать HTML-код без браузера, скрипты без интерпретатора...